# iOS , Phone gap push plugin on('notification') not triggered

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I'm using ([push-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)) to send notifications to iPhone using phone Gap.

> What I have done

- added push plugin for phoneGap project
- I'm getting device token successfully.
- I'm successfully sending
  notifications to APN using server (PHP) as backend
- **But I'm unable to receive notifications**

> Here is my working code(phoneGap - client side):

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    ios: {
        "alert": "true",
         "badge": "true",
         "sound": 'false'
    }
});
push.on('registration', function(data) {
    console.log('your device token',data.registrationId);
});
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    console.log(('test');
    console.log(data.message);
    console.log(data.title);
    console.log(data.count);
    console.log(data.sound);
    console.log(data.image);
    console.log(data.additionalData);
});
push.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
});
```

> Here is my Server code (PHP)

```
<?php

   $deviceToken = '<my _device_token>';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '<pass_phrase>';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = "This is test notification"; 
$url = "http://google.com";

if (!$message || !$url)
    exit('Example Usage: $php newspush.php \'Breaking News!\' \'https://google.com\'' . "\n");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'abcdxyz.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
  'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
  $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
  'alert' => $message,
  'sound' => 'default',
  'link_url' => $url,
  'category' => "NEWS_CATEGORY",
  );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
  echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

> ENVIRONMENT:
>   corodova version : 6.1.2
>   phonegap-plugin-push version : 1.6.2 
>   iPhone version   : 9.2
>
> **QUSETION** Why my mobile device unable to receive notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue by appending following function inside `push.on('notification',function(){});`

**push.finish()**

Example:

```
push.on('notification', function(data) 
{
       console.log(data.message);
       console.log(data.title);

       push.finish(function () 
       {
           console.log('finish successfully called');
       });    
});
```